# How to find the llvm ir code(s) that is created by a c source code?

Tags: llvm-ir

I have a c source code and I have a llvm ir code generated from the source code. How can I get the llvm ir code line(s) or the block which has the line(s) corresponding to a particular c source code line automatically (i.e., not manually)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get LLVM bitcode line number from CPP source code line number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57387315/how-to-get-llvm-bitcode-line-number-from-cpp-source-code-line-number)